# how we resolve 500 Internal Server Error/

Tags: php, json

i make a api using php, when i interact with my api an 500 internal server  error occure. how we resolve this error.

here is the my index file of api.

```
<?php 
app->post('/register',function() use($app){

$id=$app->request->post('id');

$city_name=$app->request->post('cityName');
$db= new dbHelper();
$res=$db->enterDataToTable($id,$city_name);
if($res==User_Create){
     echo "User Enter successful";
}else if($res==User_Not_Create) {
    echo "User not enter.";
}});
```

or .htaccess file below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have you looked in the logs to see what is causing the error?

Comment: Use PHP error logging to find out more?

Comment: `User_Create` is defined ?

Comment: Like one appears to be a syntax error - undefined constant app. User create also undefined. Please show a more realistic example of your code because this (hopefully) isn't it